# Angular Form validator only works when typing in text box

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am developing a small app in angular5 with PHP. I have an issue in validating form. Form validator works fine when I input data by typing in keyboard. But it is not working when I fill data with javascript.

**For example**

In email field,

If I type `myemail` , Its showing invalid email. works good.
But If I set using javascript like `$('#email').value('asdsa@gmail.com')` its not  working.

[image: Form]

[image: Validator]

[image]

What is wrong? I am new to Angular5.

Comment: instead of directly manipulating DOM, try setting value of `form control` manually `this.registerForm.controls['email'].setValue('example@abc.com')`

Comment: What u mean? How?

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of screen shot

Comment: `Sarthak Aggarwal` Works thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use below code for setting up the value in the form control. pleas refer angular doc for more information https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

```js
this.registerForm.controls.email.setValue('asdsa@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just say see this [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue)

```
this.registerForm.patchValue({
email: 'asdsa@gmail.com'
});
```

or you can assign it initially while creating a form like,

```
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
email: ['asdsa@gmail.com']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, angular does not know when jQuery affects the Physical DOM(therefore not knowing when to run its check on variables to cause a change). In order to do this, you have to initiate a change cycle to angular after your jquery action.